# Send Extra Parameters with jqGrid Edit Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use the jqgrid free version. I need to send an extra parameter along with the edit callback using inline editing.

This is my code but the extra parameters are not getting to the servlet.

```
$("#csstsoplacardarrangmentlist").jqGrid   ('inlineNav',"#csstsoplacardarrangmentlistpager",
    {edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:true,view:false},
    {editParams: {editRowParams:{keys: true, extraparam: {quickfillflag:$('.quickfillflag2').prop("checked")}}}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you included in your question contains property `extraparam` with the value `{quickfillflag:$('.quickfillflag2').prop("checked")}`. The object will be initialized *once* during executing of `inlineNav`. Additionally you use `editRowParams` property, which is unknown. You should place properties of inline editing directly under `editParams`.

If I correctly understand your problem then the problem will be solved by usage `quickfillflag` defined as function:

```
$("#csstsoplacardarrangmentlist").jqGrid('inlineNav', 
    "#csstsoplacardarrangmentlistpager",
    { edit: true, add: false },
    {
        editParams: {
            keys: true,
            extraparam: {
                quickfillflag: function () {
                    return :$('.quickfillflag2').prop("checked");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Additionally I'd recommend you to specify the options of inline editing inside of `inlineEditing` option of jqGrid. After that you can reduce the option of `inlineNav`. For example, you can use jqGrid options

```
inlineNavOptions: {
    edit: true,
    add: false
},
inlineEditing: {
    keys: true,
    extraparam: {
        quickfillflag: function () {
            return :$('.quickfillflag2').prop("checked");
        }
    }
}
```

and to use `inlineNav` as

```
$("#csstsoplacardarrangmentlist").jqGrid('inlineNav');
```